# How can I change a size option in select with animate

Tags: jquery, parameters, html-select

How can I change a size option in select with `animate` in jQuery.
I wrote these two functions, but the second uses `animate` and doesn't work with size parameter.

```
$.fn.pasa_encima_selector = function () {
    $(this).hover(function () {
        $(this).attr('size', 15);
    },
    function() {
        $(this).attr('size', 1);
    });
};

$.fn.pasa_encima_selector_b = function () {
    $(this).hover(function () {
        $(this).unbind('hover');
        $(this).animate({height: 300}, 200, function() {

            $(this).mouseout(function () {
                $(this).unbind('mouseout');
                $(this).animate({height: 67}, 200, function () {
                $('.selector_ampliacion').pasa_encima_selector();
                });
            });

        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Can you try to rephrase your question?

Comment: yeah, please rephrase it

Comment: He's trying to animate the 'size' attribute. Which is deprecated by the way.

Answer (score 1):

```
function sincdec(){
if(($("select").attr("size"))==1){
    var mi="inc";
    var s=1;
    setInterval(function(){
        if(s<10){
            if($('#select').is(':hover') === true){
                s++;$("select").attr("size",s);
                $("span").html(s);
            }
        }
    },10);
}
else if(($("select").attr("size"))==10){
    var mi="dec";
    var s=10;
    setInterval(function(){
        if(s>1){
            if($('#select').is(':hover') === false){
                s--;$("select").attr("size",s);
                $("span").html(s);
            }
        }
    },10);
}
};

$("select").hover(function(e){
   sincdec();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/krabat1/xsCq4/

​